# How to deal with server responses which arrive in wrong order in react frontend?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I have a search input field in my react frontend where the user can type and whenever the value changes a post request is sent to web server which communicates with elastic search. The problem is the following:

- User starts to type: "h" => search request is sent and takes a long time since many entries contain "h".
- User finishes typing: "hello" => search request is sent again but takes much shorter

Result: React first gets the response for "hello" and then for "h". So the result for h overwrites the result for "hello" which is not want I want.

How can I fix that?

EDIT:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    doSearch();
  }, [query, cbTitle, cbAbstract, cbAuthor, cbInstitution]); // trickered when input (aka query or cb=Checkboxes) changes 

doSearch(){
...
    axios
      // .post(`http://XXX:5000/search`, data, axios_config)
      .post(`/search`, data, axios_config)
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res);
        // console.log(res.data);
        setSearchResponse(res.data);
      });
  };
}
```

EDIT 2: approach mentioned in answer

```
    axios
      .post(`http://XXX:5000/search`, data, axios_config)
      // .post(`/search`, data, axios_config)
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res);
        // console.log(res.data);
        if (
          res.data["query"] === query &&
          res.data["location"] === searchLocation
        ) {
          console.log("latest state:");
          console.log(query);
          setSearchResponse(res.data["result"]);
        }
      });
  };
```

EDIT 3: whole component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "./CardPaper";
import axios from "axios";

let axios_config = {
  headers: {
    data: { location: "aits" },
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true,
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  },
};

function Search() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [cbTitle, setcbTitle] = useState(true);
  const [cbAbstract, setcbAbstract] = useState(true);
  const [cbAuthor, setcbAuthor] = useState(true);
  const [cbInstitution, setcbInstitution] = useState(true);
  const [searchLocation, setSearchLocation] = useState("");
  const [searchResponse, setSearchResponse] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    doSearch();
  }, [query, cbTitle, cbAbstract, cbAuthor, cbInstitution]);

  const doSearch = () => {
    let search_location = "";
    if (cbTitle === true) {
      search_location += "t";
    }
    if (cbAuthor === true) {
      search_location += "a";
    }
    if (cbAbstract === true) {
      search_location += "s";
    }
    if (cbInstitution === true) {
      search_location += "i";
    }
    setSearchLocation(search_location);
    let data = { query: query, location: search_location };
    axios
      .post(`http://XXX:5000/search`, data, axios_config)
      // .post(`/search`, data, axios_config)
      .then((res) => {
        if (
          res.data["query"] === query &&
          res.data["location"] === searchLocation
        ) {
          console.log("latest state:");
          console.log(query);
          setSearchResponse(res.data["result"]);
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto">
      <input
        className="block mx-auto w-1/2 border-2 border-gray-300 bg-white h-10 px-5 pr-16 rounded-lg mt-8 focus:outline-none"
        type="search"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Search for title, author or phrases in the abstract of a paper"
        value={query}
        onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div className="mx-auto w-1/2">
        <div>
          <span className="pl-2">found {searchResponse.length} results</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className="ml-3 block md:inline">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="text-gray-600"
              defaultChecked={cbTitle}
              onChange={() => {
                setcbTitle(!cbTitle);
              }}
            />
            <span className="ml-2 text-gray-700">Title</span>
          </label>
          <label className="ml-3 block md:inline">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="ext-gray-600"
              checked={cbAbstract}
              onChange={() => {
                setcbAbstract(!cbAbstract);
              }}
            />
            <span className="ml-2 text-gray-700">Abstract</span>
          </label>
          <label className="ml-3 block md:inline">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="text-gray-600"
              checked={cbAuthor}
              onChange={() => {
                setcbAuthor(!cbAuthor);
              }}
            />
            <span className="ml-2 text-gray-700">Author</span>
          </label>
          <label className="ml-3 block md:inline">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="ext-gray-600"
              checked={cbInstitution}
              onChange={() => {
                setcbInstitution(!cbInstitution);
              }}
            />
            <span className="ml-2 text-gray-700">Institution</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      {searchResponse.map(function (item, index) {
        return (
          <Card
            title={item["title"]}
            abstract={item["abstract"]}
            authors={item["authors"]}
            affliatedInstitutions={item["institutions"]}
            link={item["url"]}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: How do you send the request? Can you show some code?

Comment: Maybe debounce?

Comment: What do you mean by debounce? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One option is Store the latest searched text in client side and check it with the response before doing DOM updation.

Example: The below function will give you an idea, I stored the user input in a variable(latestInput) and in the response I bring the same data and did the comparison. If both matched do the updation.

```
function postSearchData()
{
   axios
  .post(`/search`, data, axios_config)
  .then((res) => {
    if(res.data.searchText === query)
       setSearchResponse(res.data);
  });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help since the state still just gets overwritten.

Comment: @siva I edited the answer, you can compare the response with the state object. The state object will always have the latest query

Comment: @siva The best approach is put console.log inside the axios response and see what value is coming for seachText and query

Comment: http://cvpr20.janruettinger.com here is a live example. You can go type something in e.g. "Oxford" and then have a look at the console. I have also made another edit to my question to show how I do the console log. Do you have an idea why it still doesn't work?

Comment: @siva The call is not working in my end. could you check
console.log(query); console.log(res.data["query"])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217546/discussion-between-linoy-and-siva).

Comment: @siva please accept the answer if it worked,  thanks

Comment: Will do. Right now it's still not working. I am in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
let ignore = false;
async function fetchProduct() {
  const response = await fetch('http://myapi/product/' + productId);
  const json = await response.json();
  if (!ignore) setProduct(json);
}

fetchProduct();
return () => { ignore = true };
```

}, [productId]);

above approach will fix the out-of-order requests issue. Tested in local, works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an index in the setSearchResponse